# error: cannot access InternalTokenProvider FirebaseAuth mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

> error: cannot access InternalTokenProvider for com.google.firebase.internal.InternalTokenProvider not found 
>   FirebaseAuth mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
>                                   ^
>       class file for com.google.firebase.internal.InternalTokenProvider not found
>       Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>       Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>       1 error

This is the error I got while running the app.The compiler does not even compile it thows the error

These are the dependancies I am using.

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
```

It shows the same error in every place where I use

```
 FirebaseAuth auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
```

From the docs:

> Update - June 12, 2018
>
> Your app gradle file now has to explicitly list com.google.firebase:firebase-core as a dependency for Firebase services to work as expected.

Comment: I have added the firebase core dependancy but again shows the same error.

Comment: upgrade firebase-auth to the  following `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'`

Comment: Thank you @Peter Haddad for your quick help! Now it's working fine.

Comment: @user9248098 please mark the answer as correct by clicking the check mark next to it, thank you!

Comment: make sure to have latest version of both `core` and `auth` implementations